# Max Wifi TX by country

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, power, default-settings

I can't remember which country have the max wifi transmission power authorised ?

I'm thinking about "BO" m'I right? 
Also what Iso country is BO ? Bolivia?

Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

India seems to have the better TX (just behind Canada)

Result:

```
Ireland : 2.4 Ghz, Channel 4, mode N, SNR  45, Signal -40 - Signal % 60%
          5Ghz,    Channel 112, AC,   SNR 36, Signal -49 - Signal % 51%

India : 2.4 Ghz, Channel 4, mode N, SNR  64, Signal -23 - Signal % 76%
          5Ghz,    Channel 112, AC,   SNR 40, Signal -50 - Signal % 50%
```

*5Ghz is actually slower and unstable.

Obviously you need to be in the same country.

Comment: So if I want the best Wi-Fi signal, I should hop over to Ireland or India when I need to work on my computer?

Comment: India actually, Ireland is my default country, it was just here for a comparison, but India is faster alright